# Display Form data on popup\modal when submitted in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, modal-dialog

I have a form with submit button. On clicking the submit button, popup\modal should appear displaying the data of the form submitted. I am using Bootstrap and Angular. So how do I store the data and display on the modal? Here is the code in html

HTML

```
    <form >     
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />      
  
    <select aria-label="Default select city">
      <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">London</option>
      <option value="2">Paris</option>
      <option value="3">NYC</option>
    </select>     
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>      
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many solutions to your "question" since it is not a specific problem.

You can save the form data in localStorage. Create a service to store the form data in an appropiate way into the localStorage and then retrieve it from another page ( the success page maybe? ) showing the information the way you want.

If you are looking for a better solution then you will have to implement some state management into your application.

You could create your own implementation using Events and services but I highly recommend you using some library like [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/)

Comment: Is there a way I can use without service or NGRX?

Comment: The thing is, are you doing it all in one component? Do you have several components with routes so you have the form page and the success page? You could do it without services or state management. But forget about clean code, mantainability, readability, scalability, etc, etc, etc

Comment: It is a single component, just needed the popup to display the data when the button clicked. doesn't really need any other features.

Comment: What kind of forms are you using, your question is far to be specific

Comment: using Reactive form

Comment: I have edited with code. Please have a look